# Strip and replace variable if it contains two words

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I was wondering how to split/replace a variable into two seperate words when the variable contains a -slash- or a comma. I want to use this so that I can create two classes on a list element and then add a gradient to that div.

I've created a script that grabs some values from a JSON file. These values can be:

- Black
- White
- Black / White

How do I test if the variable contains two words or a `/` and then change `Black / White` to "black" and "white"? Or in the code:

```
<li class="black white"></li>
```

Below the complete script that I tried. The error I get right now is that when color is just one word (so black or white) the script breaks because `colorClean[1]` is not recognized.

```
$.each(custom.values, function(index, value){
   var color = (value.title).toLowerCase();

   colorClean = color.split('/');
   one = colorClean[0].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
   two = colorClean[1].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");

// I need two variables if the string contains two words so I can do this, where var 1 and 2 are two colors:
colorClean.css("background-image", "-webkit-linear-gradient(top, var1 0%,var2 100%)");
///////////////////////////////////////
          var productHtml = '' +
              '<li class="'+ colorClean +'"></li>'; 

          productsHtml.push(productHtml);
        });
        productsHtml = productsHtml.join('');

        $('.product.'+id+' .colours').html('<ul>'+productsHtml+'</ul>');
```

Comment: Why dont you check whether the string actually has a `/` before doing operations.Something like this `if(color.indexOf("/")!=-1)` then do operations else if it doesnt have `/` then you can proceed directly.

Comment: You're overthinking this I think. Just replace the "/" with " " (a space). If the "/" is not there it won't replace anything.

Comment: @All: Ok can somebody post some kind of example then?

Comment: An fyi: These `/^\s*/` and `/\s*$/` should be used with a 1 or more quantifier `+` instead of a 0 or more `*`. The reason is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the "/"

Change:

```
colorClean = color.split('/');
one = colorClean[0].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
two = colorClean[1].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
```

to

```
var colorClean = color.replace("/"," ");
```

or

```
var colorClean = color.replace(/\s?\/\s?/," ");  //results in "black" or "white", or "black white"
```

There is no need to split and strip.

---

And since you added another requirement, you can make the array either with a different match or a split.

```
var colorClean = color.replace(/\s?\/\s?/," ");
var colors = colorClean.split(/\s+/);
if (colors.length===1) {
    colors[1] = colors[0];
}
console.log(colorClean, colors[0]. colors[1]);
```

Comment: Ok but how does this return two variables?? I need two seperate variables to be place inside a `.css()` function! I want to do something like `colorClean.css("background-image", "-webkit-linear-gradient(top, var1 0%,var2 100%)");` where `var1` and `var2` are the two colors.

Comment: And in your original code you never had that restriction from what you showed.

Comment: Sorry for my dumbness!! Ok I think I know what you have done except that I don't know anymore how to incorporate the css() bit.

Comment: Use the array instead of the variables... `"-webkit-linear-gradient(top," + colors[0] + " 0%," + colors[1] + " 100%)");`

Answer (score 0):

Simple, `split` to array and count it.

```
if (colorClean.split('/').length > 1 || colorClean.split(' ').length > 1) {
```

Or you can try a regex:

```
if (colorClean.split(/\s|\//).length > 1)
```

Or simply check if it exists:

```
if (typeof colorClean[1] !== 'undefined') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can check if a certain character exists with `indexOf(char)` and if you want to separate them, you can use a JavaScript function called [`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) instead a reg exp (for more complex situations). Split will return an array with as many positions as splits have occurs.